# Time and space complexity of the algorithm

Tags: python, algorithm, performance, time-complexity, space-complexity

I'm reading a book on algorithmic puzzles and came across an interesting problem. The puzzle itself is not that hard, but I'm having a hard time understanding the time and space complexity. The puzzle goes like this:

> Given an array of integers that are out of order, determine the bounds
> of the smallest window that must be sorted in order for the entire
> array to be sorted. For example, given [3, 7, 5, 6, 9], you should
> return (1, 3).

The solution that the author provides is:

```
def smallest_window(array):
  left, right = None, None
  s = sorted(array)

  for i in range(len(array)):
    if array[i] != s[i] and left is None:
        left = i
    elif array[i] != s[i]:
        right = i
  return left, right
```

The author claims that both time and space complexities are **O(n log n)**. I see how time complexity can be O(n log n), the sorting algorithm takes the longest, and it could be O(n log n) in python. However, I do not understand why the space complexity is O(n log n). We save the copy of the array which takes O(n) space and left/right pointers, which are constant. So shouldn't the space complexity be **O(n)**?

Comment: yes, I agree with you that the space complexity is O(n) for the sorted array, unless we assume that the built-in sorting algorithm needs O(n * log n) additional space to do its job.

Comment: @user1984 Python uses Timsort, which takes O(n) space https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort

Comment: Although it is in `O(n))`, there is no contradiction to write the space complexity is in `O(n log n)` as well. Just a looser bound, but correct.

Comment: @OmG Thank you for your response. I think it depends. O(px) is a well-defined function, and for every polynomial expression, it returns a particular expression. So for 2 + n, it returns n. in that sense there is a contradiction. But if he said that the time complexity is not bigger than O(n log n), there would be no contradiction. Altought even in that case, if the function is cannot possibly be bigger than O(n), why not just say it's O(n)? We might as well say that the time and space are not bigger than O(n!)

Comment: @Hayk, the thing is that big-O notation is used differently by many coders than mathematicians. Wikipedia has *"A description of a function in terms of big O notation **usually** only provides an upper bound on the growth rate of the function."* (my highlight)."  But I agree that the author should just have said O(n), and probably had a bad night sleep before writing this.

Comment: In the transdichotomous model, this algorithm is O(n log n) time, and Theta(n) space.

Comment: @trincot I see. Probably))

Comment: @PaulHankin I do not think we're using that model in the book, because, everything else is estimated in regular big O. But thanks, did not even know about such thing, I'll check that up)

Comment: @ggorlen 
`Daily Coding Problem: Get exceptionally good at coding interviews by solving one problem every day - By Lawrence Wu, Alex Miller `
Just started. Doesn't seem to be a great book, doesn't seem to be too bad either.